# How to get query strings in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, database

I am interested in profiling SQL Server database transactions that are being executed by a java application.

Particularly I am interested in finding out what queries (query strings) get executed as a part of the transaction.

Database I am using is SQL Server 2008.

Right now I am selecting `Exec Prepared SQL` event and `Prepare SQL` event in the profiler but that does not give me the query strings that are being executed by the application. I see a bunch of `exec` statements but nothing more. It doesn't have details as to what query was being executed.

Would anyone have an idea of how can I get access to the query strings?

Regards,

Comment: Well, what events is your trace collecting? Also, you know that [Profiler can really kill the performance of your server](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events), right? ([Also see this post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/observer-overhead-the-perils-of-too-much-tracing/).)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Collecting the following events
SQL:Batch Starting
SQL:Batch Completed
SQL:Statement Starting
SQL:Statement Completed

I am looking into the TextData column of the trace but dont see any query strings.

Comment: Also this is just to debug a problem that we are seeing. Thanks for the tip though. Am aware that profiling can kill server performance.

Comment: Check the video tutorial on [Mastering SQL Server Profiler](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Video/66676/) - excellent stuff

Answer (score 2):

My typicals are:

```
RPC:Completed.
SP Completed.
SP:StmtCompleted

Exec Prepared SQL
SQL : BatchCompleted
SQL : StmtCompleted
```

And I pick the TextData columnn (and some others).

Do you know about DMV queries?

http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero/

http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero-in-2011/

Comment: None of these settings actually give me the query strings that were executed for the transaction. Am I missing something? :S

Comment: When in doubt, check everything under "Stored Procedures" and "TSQL" and "Transactions".  Add everything under "Sessions" just to make sure you profiling the same db that you think your activity is occurring on.  Then fine-tune down after you start getting the info-overload.